# Select option's text is different once selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

## Problem

This is hard to explain, so please bear with me. I came across a curious scenario today that I solved, but I'm not sure why my solution works.

I created a group of selects and wrote a script that constrains you from selecting the same option more than once by removing the selected option from the other select lists.

However in **IE(including IE9)**, the option list was displaying the wrong option, but once selected it would display the right option.

[image]

### Re-create the error

In my first script you can get to this state by doing the following:

*NOTE: This is IE only. Works fine in Chrome*

**Script:** http://jsfiddle.net/s6F4h/37/

1. In the first drop down choose 3
2. In the second drop down choose 1
3. In the first drop down choose 1 (should not be an available option)
4. Notice that the selected value is 2!
5. Notice that changing your selected value in the second drop down also produces different values than those presented.
6. Lastly, notice that the DOM is displaying the correct values
   [image]

### Fix the error (magically)

Now for my fix which I found by random guess work...

**Script:** http://jsfiddle.net/s6F4h/36/

Creating my selects like this causes the strange behavior:

```
var $S1 = $('<select class="question" />');
```

Creating my selects like this corrects that behavior:

```
var $S1 = $('<select />', {'class': 'question'});
```

### Follow Up

- What is the difference in the above two jQuery objects?
- How in the world can IE show one thing in its DOM and another on the actual page (I know CSS [content](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html) can do this, but there's no CSS involved)? Wouldn't be so bad if this was just an IE6-8 thing, but it's reproducible in IE9!
- Could it be an IE bug or a jQuery bug?

Lastly, maybe I've just done something incredibly stupid, and in my hysteria have concocted some absurd conclusion. Please, *gently*, inform me if I have done so.

Comment: Your fiddle (and a [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6F4h/19/) that uses the `select` format that you said caused the problem) seem fine to me in IE9.

Comment: This selector: `> option:selected` is not syntactically valid, is it? I don't think you can start a selector with `>` like that (and it's not necessary anyway).

Comment: @JamesAllardice - the modified fiddle you've provided still causes the issue (In my IE browser anyway...).

Comment: Also your first fiddle (16) works perfectly fine in IE9 as far as I can tell.  I don't understand the problem description however.

Comment: @BrandonBoone - I can't reproduce the problem following your steps in either your fiddle or mine in IE9, 8 or 7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Oh wait - I see what's happening. Well you're messing with the innards of a `<select>` in IE, and that's always been risky. Give me a sec ...

Comment: @Pointy It's valid, though `$(this).children('option:selected')` may be a better fit. The leading `>` is a [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes, I know it's a child selector, but syntactically it's supposed to be an operator **between** selector expressions.  Without another selector expression on the left, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski well "selectoracle" interprets it as `* > option` which I guess makes sense, though it's definitely pointless if that's accurate :-)

Comment: @Pointy Ah, sorry. The left-side of the operator is each element in the current collection. So, it ends up being treated as `{this} > option:selected`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski are you sure that jQuery interprets it that way?  (It might; I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: Wow, [selectoracle](http://tux.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py) looks like an awesome tool. Also, never thought that much into the `find('> element')` construct. I certainly didn't invent it, but I always assumed(deadly word) that it simply referenced the preceding object. If it doesn't, then I've got a lot of refactoring to do.

Comment: @Pointy Haven't found an example in the docs, but it does perform that way: http://jsfiddle.net/coiscir/G6Tth/1/.

Comment: Welp learn something every day. Anyway @BrandonBoone that behavior does look extremely weird, and the fact that constructing the `<select>` elements differently affects it makes me think that's it's an IE behavior weirdness that jQuery doesn't consistently handle.

Comment: @Pointy - well, guess it's time to submit a bug into the Microsoft void.... Thanks for looking into this though! At least I know I'm not going crazy.

Comment: [Filed a bug report with jQuery](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12002). Still working on filing with Microsoft. Will post an answer if they respond with something that can close out this question.

Comment: Your code contains bug. Try to change value multiple times on the same select. :) Focus doesn't cut it, you must reset prev after each change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two DOM objects is not a matter of data, but rather a matter of the order of operations when they are created.

When you use the inline of `$('<select class="blah" />')`, the `<select>` element is created with the class already intact, and styled accordingly. When you use $(`<select />`, { 'class': 'blah' })`, you perform 2 operations: 1) create the item, 2) set it's class.

This seems innocuous, but it actually forces the browser to do a redraw of the element upon application of the CSS class.

Now - in your scenario, the fact that this causes the specific issue that it does is pretty clearly a bug that applies to IE - but the fact that IE **shouldn't** behave poorly obviously in no way prevents it from doing so.

Hope this sheds some light.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
`$("select.question").val('[what ever selection you want selected');`
```

to make it work.  Or perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: It's not so much a question of how to make it work (I already have that solution above). It's more a question of weather or not the original broken code was due to a bug in jQuery and/or Internet Explorer. I submitted a [bug on the jQuery website](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12002) which was recently moved into an open status. So it appears they are acknowledging the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Glad it's working.  You may have found a bug.  I would be interested in the results.